# Arduino Pro Mini (5v) I2C pullups

Tags: i2c, arduino-pro-mini, esp32

I recently bought an ESP-WROOM-32 module and I want it to talk to my Pro Mini via I2C. Do I have to pull-up the lines to the 3.3v side (ESP32)? Since the Pro Mini runs at 5v, I think it's a bad idea to pull-up the lines from that side.

Comment: That would work. 3.3V is high enough for the 5V arduino to register as a HIGH. Just make sure you disable the internal pull up resistors on the Arduino. The default I2C library enables those for some reason (which it shouldn't imho).

Comment: @Gerben, the i2c signal needs to be 3.5V for an atmega328p at 5V. A digital input requires 3.0V, but the i2c needs 3.5V.

Comment: Indeed; Vih is 0.7*Vcc, so according to the datasheet you'd need at least 3.5V. But my guess is it will work just fine. If not, you could use [two mosfets to create a I2C level shifter](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10441.pdf)

Comment: note that you can feed your esp32 3.6v within spec.

Comment: @Gerben It works, I pulled-up the lines with 4k7 resistors on 3v3 side. Since the ESP32 has a higher core speed, I need to put a 5ms on every request for the Pro Mini to keep up.